# Find and return the next smallest value larger than q of a balanced tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the next smallest element that is larger than the parameter q.  I approached to follow q down until the key found is larger than q, and return it.  However, if that key is equal to q I will have to go back up until I find the previous node where I originally gone left.  I tried so many ways but still can't figure out where should I create the pointer to keep track of that node so my code will go right once and then go all the way to the left to find the key. Any suggestion?

```
  int find_next_larger(tree_node_t *tree, int q)
{
    tree_node_t * tmp_node;
    tree_node_t * took_left_node = NULL;
    if (tree->left == NULL)
        return(NULL); // empty tree returns null
    else
    {
        tmp_node = tree; 

        while (tmp_node-> right != NULL)
        {
            if (q < tmp_node->key)
            {
                tmp_node = tmp_node->left;  // if q is smaller than node go to left 
            }
            else
            {
                tmp_node = tmp_node->right; //otherwise go right
            }       
        }
        if (tmp_node->key > q)
            return tmp_node->left;
        else
        {
            //got stuck here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call this algorithm **Upper Bounded**

The algorithm is as follows:

### Recursive

- If tree is empty return `positive infinity`
- If `q` is less than root of current tree, then return `min(root, UpperBounded(left subtree))`
- Else return `UpperBounded(right subtree)`

### Non-recursive

- let upper = positive_infinity
- let curr = root
- While curr != NULL

  - If q < curr

    - upper = min(upper, curr)
    - curr = curr->left
  - Else

    - curr = curr->right
- return upper

I've minimally tested this, but if you find any errors with it, you may report here

Comment: Not my pathway so I can't really understand it.

Comment: @user6820297 it's pseudocode. You have to convert the statements to code

Comment: Can you explain what does upper = postive_infinity means? I have never assigned an infinitely value.

Comment: @user6820297 in terms of a binary search tree, positive infinity means the largest value that you can store in the tree. In your case, you could set some integer to the value 2^31 - 1. This is the maximum positive integer that can be stored in the tree